# access reference without knowing reference name

Tags: java, swing, jframe, windowlistener

I have a class named NetPosition which has a JFrame and that JFrame contains a button which if clicked makes object of another class called BuyScreen and opens another JFrame.THe problem is when the parent frame is closing i want all the BuyScreen frames to be closed.Something like this

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {

    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override

    /*Closing all the buy screens and sells screens of marketwatch before market watch screen is closed*/
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(BuySellNetPosition.countBuySellNetPosition!=0)
        {
            BuySellNetPosition.frame
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

The child frame is not static.I can have several BuyScreen frames opened at the same time.Is it possible to close all frames of a particular class without knowing the names of references to that class.
Previously i made an array of BuyScreen objects to handle this problem.But i am wondering if there is another way.

Comment: See also [*The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/230513)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you create a new `BuyScreen`, you should be adding it as a listener to your main frame that you want to respond to. That way, whenever the main frame closes, it will notify all the `BuyScreen` frames that you want to close.

You don't need to maintain a collection of the frames yourself. The `addWindowListener()` call will do that for you.

Your `windowClosing()` implementation within the `BuyScreen` just needs to check that it's the main window that's the source of the event, and then close itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store all your `BuyScreens` in some sort of collection eg. `LinkedList<ButScreen>`. You will be able to iterate over that collection and close alle related `BuyScreens`.

Or use `JDialogs` with parent set as your `BuyScreens`. They will all close automaticly when the parent frame/dialog will be closed.

Comment: hey thanks for answering.i have done what you are suggesting me before.i was just wondering if there is any other way to solve the problem.

Comment: If you have in mind the collection, that it is the simplest and most traightforward way to deal with it